# SELECT To obtain results from two tables where a value occurs once only in a table column

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

Sorry I know this should be relatively simple and probably has been answered before, but I've got myself blocked on this and can't find a post here that matches.

I have two tables companies and contacts. A contact can be linked to 0 or 1 company, a company can have 1 or more contacts and MAY have one set as a 'primary contact'

companies(ccyID,ccyname,primconID)

```
________________________________________________
|  ccyID      |  ccyname      |  PrimconID    |
------------------------------------------------
|  aaaaaaa    |  Company A    |    NULL       |
|  bbbbbbb    |  Company B    |    NULL       |
|  ccccccc    |  Company C    |   vvvvvvv     |
________________________________________________
```

contacts(conID,firstname,lastname,ccyID)

```
__________________________________________________
|  conID    | first     | last      | companyID |
--------------------------------------------------
|  zzzzzzz  |  Stand    |   Alone   |   NULL    |
|  yyyyyyy  |  Only     |   Contact |  aaaaaaa  |
|  xxxxxxx  |  CompanyB |   First   |  bbbbbbb  |
|  wwwwwww  |  CompanyB |   Second  |  bbbbbbb  |
|  vvvvvvv  |  CompanyC |   Only    |  ccccccc  |
_________________________________________________
```

I need a SELECT that will return the companyID and contactID when the  company has exactly one contact, AND does not have a PrimconID set i.e. for the above data I want returned

```
conID   ccyID
----------------
yyyyyyy aaaaaaa
```

(The eventual idea is that I'm then going to update the tables to make the solitary contact for companies the primary contact)

Answer (score 0):

Use a CTE to first identify all contacts having only a single company, and then join to the company table:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT ccyID, MAX(conID) AS conID
    FROM contacts
    GROUP BY ccyID
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
)

SELECT
    t.conID,
    c.ccyID
FROM companies c
INNER JOIN cte t
    ON c.ccyID = t.ccyID
WHERE
    c.PrimconID IS NULL;
```

See the demo below to see the query working.

### Demo

Comment: Wrong way round - all contacts have either 0 or 1 company. It's companies that have only 1 contact that I am trying to identify. But a CTE is a good solution.

Comment: @grl570810 My answer is [working in this demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b10888305cfbec9064a8baf199348dd4).  Did you bother to check it?

Comment: Sorry I didn't pick up on your reply earlier I'm not a frequent Stack Overflow attendee. It's very interesting looking at the demo the query does indeed work when used on MySQL but I was using Microsoft SQL Server and it came up with syntax errors. Possibly in attempting to correct those I munged the logic.

Comment: @grl570810 [The same code also runs in SQL Server](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b10888305cfbec9064a8baf199348dd4).

Answer (score 0):

Group contacts by company to keep only those with a count of 1 and make sure they are in the set of companies without primary contact:

```
select companyid, max(conid)
from contacts
group by companyid
having count(*) = 1
and companyid in (select ccyid from companies where primconid is null)
order by companyid;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `join` and `group by`:

```
select c.ccyid, max(co.conid)
from companies c join
     contacts co
     on co.companyid = c.ccyid
where c.PrimconID is null
group by c.ccyid
having min(co.conID) = max(co.conID);
```

As an `update` statement, you can do:

```
update c
    set PrimconID = co.conid
    from companies c join
         (select co.companyid, max(co.conid) as conid
          from contacts co
          group by companyid
          having min(co.conid) = max(co.conid)
         ) co
         on co.companyid = c.ccyid
    where c.PrimconID is null ;
```

Comment: I like this answer - should have realised myself that the min & max values being the same if there's only one entry.

Comment: For the update (there's actually a  bit more to that than I let on in my question). I used this SELECT to populate a cursor which I then looped through. Possibly not very efficient but this is a one-off exercise and coming from a traditional programmer background rather than starting in SQL I find the FOR loop logic of cursor processing easier to follow.